# How to build folders hierarchy with laravel?

Tags: laravel

This is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Folder extends Model
{
protected $with = ['children'];

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Folder','parent_id')/*->select('title','path','size','ext','isFolder')*/;
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}

public static function tree() {

    return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 4, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get();

}
}
```

and i'm displaying the results with this function :

```
 $folders = Folder::tree();
```

I'm trying to display every folder and it's content whether it's a file or another directory is there a way to do this without having to do a foreach loop for every level ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#local-scopes). If you are also familiar with [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) the code I'm going to write will be easy to understand. Anwyay everything is explained with the comments.

```php
/**
 * Retrieve recursively the related children building a tree.
 * Pay attention! this scope may cause A LOT of performance problems. Expecially when there are a lot of children / nephews
 * 
 * @param  Buider  $query
 * @param  integer  $deep  
 * @param  integer $index
 * @return Builder
 */
public function scopeTree($query, $deep, $index = 0) {
  // Increment index
  $index++;

  // Current model is root, let's find the id for base case.
  $id = $this->getKey();

  // Now build the recursive nested query
  return $query->whereHas('children', function($query) use ($deep, $index, $id) {
    // If deep is lower than index, it means we have to add a node to the tree
    if($deep < $index) {
      // Recursion
      $query->tree($deep, $index);
    } else {
      // Base case
      $query->where('parent_id', '=', $id);
    }
  });
}
```

Anyway this function may cause A LOT of performance problems, so it should be better not to go "too deep" if there are a lot of records inside the database.